# How can I deploy this Next.js/TypeSript in github pages

Tags: next.js

I have a Next.js/TypeSript app and want to deploy it to github pages but i when i run

```
npm run deploy
```

i get error of no build folder located
this is a screenshot of the folde
[image]

and the script in the package.json

```
"scripts": {
    "build": "next build && next export",
    "predeploy": "npm run build",
    "deploy": "gh-pages -d build",
    "dev": "next dev",
    "build": "next build",
    "start": "next start",
    "lint": "next lint"
  },
```

Comment: `gh-pages -d out` -- change `build` to `out`. Create an empty file named `.nojekyll` inside `out` directory before running `deploy`.

Comment: where's the out directory?

Comment: It will be generated when you run `next build && next export`. https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/static-html-export#next-export